# Creating copy of arbitrary object in Python and calling constructor

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have classes `A`, `B`, and `C` which inherit from `Foo`. Their `__init__` methods all do different things, but have a similar signature: they all take a single parameter `i` in `__init__`. Some number of instances of these classes are in a list `l`, and all mixed together. In `l`, all the objects have `i=1`.

I need to go through `l`, and for every object I see, I need to create the same object, but instantiated with `i=2` instead of `i=1`.

How do I do this?

I tried this:

```
l2 = []
for obj in l:
    obj_2 = type (obj).__init__(2)
    l2.append(obj_2)
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "create the same object". If you mean "create a brand-new distinct object of the same type", then try this:

```
obj_2 = type (obj)(2)
```

Your code, rewritten as a list comprehension:

```
l2 = [type(obj)(2) for obj in l]
```